# Angular.js ng-pattern strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have been working on a form that accepts Twitter parameters such as # and @ to populate a Twitter feed.

With Angular.js I had planned to use the built in `ng-pattern` directive to validate the input before saving, however the validation is acting extremely strangely.  It marks a "valid" string as invalid on every 2nd character of the input while typing.

Its quite hard to explain the exact behaviour so heres a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9y8DsD7Mkq184qllgCy1?p=preview).

For completeness I will add my input field with the strange `ng-pattern` here:

`<input type="text" ng-pattern="/(^|\s)@(\w+)|(^|\s)#(\w+)/g" ng-model="foo" name="foo"/>`

Comment: Do you have a need for the g option? I don't think you'd have multiple matches you'd want to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the global matching with the g option, it works if you take it out.

Calling `test` or `exec` multiple times [involves state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

Basically it's trying to move on to another match, but can't find one:

```
a = /@(\w+)$/g;
> /@(\w+)$/g
a.exec("@test")
> ["@test", "test"]
a.exec("@test")
> null
```

Comment: +1 man, i was having this issue and it was driving me nuts! thanks for the explanation! =D